# Keeping track of beacons

Tags: java, android, ibeacon, beacon, android-ibeacon

```
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {

                Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true);


                    Log.i("MainActivity", "I see a beacon that is about " + beacon.getDistance() + " meters away. ");

            }
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
}
```

I currently have 3 bluetooth beacons I want to keep track of, I want to write something like

```
If (beacon.getBluetoothAddress().equals("x") && beacon.getDistance() < beacon2.getDistance() && beacon.getDistance() < beacon3.getDistance()){
Log.i(msg: "beacon1 is the the closest to you");
```

How can I keep track of the 3 beacons?

Comment: This is a duplicate question of the one I justanswered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291417/1461050

Answer (score 0):

To find closest beacon, you can try something like this:

```
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region){

            String closestBeacon = null;
            for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                if (closestBeacon == null)
                    closestBeacon = beacon;
                else {
                    if (closestBeacon.getDistance() > beacon.getDistance()) {
                        closestBeacon = beacon;
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.i(TAG, closestBeacon.getBluetoothAddress() + " beacon is the closest to you");
        }
```