# Can not resolve symbol BeaconManagerV3

Tags: java, android, beacon

I was trying to implement a BeaconTraker from the answer @dyoung gave in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291417/11116154 but there is an import that seems to not appears in the last `android-beacon-library:2.16.3`.

How can I resolve this as long as it gives me a `'can not resolve symbol'` at line `import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManagerV3;`?

Comment: Have you tried to Invalidate Caches / Restart? If not, click `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart`.

Answer (score 0):

The `BeaconManagerV3` is an experimental new V3 API for the Android Beacon Library.  You can find it in a branch [here](https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library/blob/new-api/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconManagerV3.java)

If you want to use the BeaconTracker class mentioned above you can either:

1. Copy the BeaconManagerV3 implementation into your project.
2. Adapt the BeaconTracker to use the standard BeaconManager class included in the Android Beacon Library version 2.x.  Both BeaconManager and BeaconManagerV3 are very similar.  The V3 variant just simplifies things a bit so you don't need to bind before using other API methods.

Comment: Thank you. I think it's now working though still it's my starting point. Voting up.